# Rhythmbox keeps changing track to a different album

Tags: sound, rhythmbox

I'm not sure whats happened but when i try and listen to a song in an album just after the song has finished and should go onto the next track it starts to play stereophonics (the same album) rather than the next track, has anyone else had this problem!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your "play queue". It probably has the offending music queued.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have only the one genre/artist/album selected and you have shuffle/repeat turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have repeat on? `Control > Repeat`